# How do you move the last bone with IK without it rotating?

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I have a line of 3 bones, and I want to be able to move the last bone, without it rotating, but I also want to be able to manually rotate it outside of IK. How do I do this?

I want to be able to move the last bone in this chain, like in this picture, without it rotating.

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe create a second IK instead of creating a chain of 3 bones?

Comment: What do you mean a second IK? Sorry, I'm very new to rigging let alone IK, I just know how to turn on IK for a bone, and set the chain length for how far back it effects the rig.

Comment: please show some picture of your armature or even share a part of your armature, it will help to understand what you want

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NQExBJ9
The red circle is a ball joint, I want to be able to move the plunger head around on the end of the arm without it rotating, but NOT lock it's rotation such that I couldn't separately rotate it.

Comment: maybe edit your question and go more in detail, show some pictures of what your want your object to do and not do

Comment: I've added the new image to the question, but it's nothing I haven't already asked

Comment: so do you want something like that? https://zupimages.net/up/21/26/rk6c.gif

Comment: Yes, exactly that :) I'm guessing you parented the separate bone to the yellow bone?

Answer (score 2):

So if you're looking for that:

[image]

Bone 3 has the *IK* constraint with a *Chain Length* of 1, its *Target* is Bone 2. Bone 2 is deparented. Bone 1 is parented to Bone 2. Bone 1 has a *Copy Location* constraint with Bone 3 as *Target*, and a *Head/Tail* value of 1.

[image]

As for your second question, if you want a sliding piston, what you could do is the following setup:

[image]

Bone 1 is parented to Bone 2 and has a *Copy Location* with Bone 3 as *Target* and *Pose Space/Pose Space*. Bone 2 is deparented. Bone 3 is parented to Bone 2 and has a *Damped Track* with Bone 4 as *Target* and *Track Axis > Y*, and a *Limit Distance* with Bone 4 as *Target*, *World Space/World Space*, set the good *Distance* value. Bone 4 is parented to Bone 5 and has a *Damped Track* with Bone 2 as *Target*.

[image]

Comment: I have it working, thank you! The bit that caught me up was that the copy location part. The location doesn't have a target option, but the rotation I have been trying with does. I set the mix to add, and inverted the axis' and this has the same effect as in the gif.

Comment: for the Location constraint, I forgot to tell to put the Head/Tail value to 1, it should work

Comment: Ah, thank you. I do have another feature one part of this rig needs to have, added onto this, but it's something that is *fine* being manual if needed. Imagine that bone 3 needs to be extendable up to 300mm. I have that working manually using 2 bones in the place of the single bone 3, with the one connected to bone 1 having a location restraint, but is it possible to make this extension automatic? (As shown here: https://imgur.com/xQjqZhu)

Comment: I won't have time to answer right now, maybe ask a new question with all the details

Comment: @JackHainsworth, I've tried a solution, see my edit

Comment: Ah thank you, I’ll try it out when I get to my computer. I tried and got somewhere last night, but the biggest issue was the Pose Space orientation. I couldn’t find one that made it rotate and move correctly.

Comment: I'm trying it now. Does it still need the IK for this to work?

Comment: no, no IK this time

Comment: Is bone 1 physically attached to bone 3? I can't get either to move using the instructions above, unless they're deparented

Comment: Bone 1 is parented to Bone 2, oh and Bone 3 is parented to Bone 2 as well, I've edited my answer